# Why does Shichika allow Princess Hitei to travel with him?

Tags: katanagatari

The closing credits of *Katanagatari* show Shichika travelling with the Princess, and being pretty friendly to her. But isn't she at least indirectly responsible for Togame's death, or did I misunderstand the part where Emonzaemon mentions that only he decided himself to kill her?

So why does Shichika let her travel with him when he would have a reason to hate her?

Answer (score 1):

Princess Hitei released Togame from her burdens and sent Shichika to thank Hitei for that. Hitei also confessed that she didn't dislike Togame. Hitei also was going along with the motives of her ancestor, not her own volition. So in a way, she killed Togame for two reasons, to alter the future and to release her from burdens/responsibilities. She semi-respects Togame in the end by cutting her long hair as short as Togame's. Even Shichika has a shred of humanity to realize that any needless killing is well, needless.

Answer (score 1):

And also because she does all the paperwork and provides with money. Stuff Shichika can't really do (he mentions it in ep 12).